# Recieving emails with AWS SES/SNS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, amazon-ses

I am trying to a create email to in app message in a rails app that I am building. I am using SES to receive inbound emails and then send them to my rails app with SNS where I am trying to process them.

I can see in my production logs that SNS is hitting my endpoint but SNS is not sending any json with the request. I have no idea how to even begin debugging this.

These are the params that SNS is sending to  `POST "/email_processor"`

```
Processing by EmailsController#recieved as HTML

 <ActionController::Parameters {"controller"=>"emails", "action"=>"recieved"} permitted: false>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution for this but I have no idea why it works. I have SES trigger and SNS which triggers lambda which sends the email to my endpoint. I have no idea why SNS is not sending any json with its request to my endpoint. SNS does send the full json payload to lambda. I'm not happy with this work around but it works.

Answer (score 1):

Since the email can be big, you can just configure SES to then save it to an S3 bucket which in turn can be used to trigger a lambda function or create a delayed job in Ruby to read and delete the files upon finishing up their work!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using SNS, configure to trigger a Lambda function upon receiving an email. Then using the Lambda function you can call your rails backend with required parameters of the mail.

Comment: I am trying this but SES is only sending the email headers and reply to the lambda function. It is not sending the email content.